# Ninja Forms – change redirect URL based on API response?

Tags: plugin-ninja-forms

How can we change the redirect_url for a redirect action based on the response from an API?

I have created a custom action (extending `NF_Abstracts_Action` )  that runs during submission with `late` timing and calls an external API.

Based on that response I want to change the page being redirected to.  I cam get the actions with `NinjaForms()->form(2)->get_actions()`, but changing the `redirect_url` of the redirect action in that array doesn’t alter the current flow.

Alternatively how can I send a querystring containing data from the API to the redirected page?

Also tried an alternate approach, of redirecting inside a `WP Hook action`

```
function ninja_test_action($form_data) {
    error_log('inside wp hook action - about to redirect');
    wp_redirect('https://wp.test');
}
add_action('ninja_test_action', 'ninja_test_action',10,1);
```

This fails with a console error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'nonce')`

This testing is being performed on a fresh and clean install of WordPress 5.9 using a clean Underscores theme and only the Ninja Forms plugin installed.

Comment: Which action triggers the logic which calls your external API?

Comment: (This sounds like a fun problem that I would love to dig into - but I am not so familiar with NF as to be able to formulate a starting point to begin digging into the NF codebase given the current information alone. Any additional insight into how the API call is hooked up to form submission would go a long way, for me!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the way I've ended up doing this is as follows. It's probably not the optimal way but I can't find a way to change the submission data during the submission workflow (the redirect action always seems to read the original entered data). Basically, the key hook is `ninja_forms_run_action_settings` where you can filter `$action_settings` which contains the redirect url.

In my Action class:

```
class CustomProcessing extends NF_Abstracts_Action {

private string $_redirect_url;

   public function __construct()
    {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->_nicename = 'Custom Process';


        add_filter( 'ninja_forms_run_action_settings', [ $this, 'changeRedirectURL' ], 10, 4 );
    }


    public function process( $action_id, $form_id, $data ) {

    // code to call API endpoint

    // set redirect url on response from API
    if ( 201 === $response[ 'response' ][ 'code' ] ) {
        $this->_redirect_url = $body_url;
    }

    return $data

}


    public function changeRedirectURL( $action_settings, $form_id, $action_id, $form_settings )
    {

        if ( '<redirect action name>' === $action_settings[ "label" ] ) {
            $action_settings[ 'redirect_url' ] = $this->_redirect_url;
        }

        return $action_settings;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend deleting the redirect action for the form, then in your code for the custom action that is run at the time of form submission to interact with the API, you can use `wp_redirect()` to redirect the user to the expected page.

Also, you can add any necessary parameters to the redirect URL passed to `wp_redirect()`.

Check out the [WP code reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/) on `wp_redirect()`.

Comment: wp_redirect() doesn't work within a Ninja Form action

Comment: Please provide details on how it's not working. I've used ```wp_redirect()``` in a WP Hook action in NF with success, so I know it does work.

Comment: A WP Hook action isn't a custom action

Comment: Yes, it is. NF changed the nomenclature of their actions to change "Custom" to "WP Hook" but it does the same thing. Just add a WP Hook action to your form and specify the hook tag (your custom function) to be called when the form is processed.

Comment: This isn't a WP Hook action, it's a new action that extends `NF_Abstracts_Action` and appears as a selectable option in the Form builder. You cannot use wp_redirect here. I've tried. It doesn't work. 

All I really need to understand is how an action can change the submission data permanently for later actions.

Comment: also, wp_redirect() does not seem to work inside a WP Hook action.